# Advanced partitions query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table that contains something similar to the following columns:

```
infopath_form_id     (integer)
form_type            (integer)
approver             (varchar)
event_timestamp      (datetime)
```

This table contains the approval history for an infopath form and each form that is submitted in the system is given a unique infopath_form_id for this to be stored against. There is no consistent number of approvers for each form (as it differs based on the value of the transaction) however there is always at least two approvers for a form. Each approval task is written as another row to the table and only history of previous approvals is stored within this table.

What I need to find out is the average time that is taken between approvals for each form type. I've tried tackling this every which way using partitions but I'm getting stuck given that there isn't a fixed number of approvers for each form. How should I approach this problem?

Comment: sql server does not have a type that is called `integer`. You probably meant `int`.

Comment: @zespri Well, yeah, obviously ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you want this:

```
SELECT infopath_form_id
     , DATEDIFF(Minutes,MIN(event_timestamp),MAX(event_timestamp))/CAST(COUNT(*)-1 AS FLOAT)
FROM Table
GROUP BY infopath_form_id
```

That will give you the average number of minutes between the first and last entry for each InfoPath_form_id.

Explanation of functions used:

1. `MIN()` returns the earliest date
2. `MAX()` returns the latest date
3. `DATEDIFF()` returns the difference between two dates in a given unit (Minutes in this example)
4. `COUNT()` returns the number of rows per grouping item (ie InfoPath_form_id)

So simply divide the total minutes elapsed by one less than the number of records giving you the average number of minutes between events.

Comment: Actually, you want to divide it by `count(*) - 1`.